# Forcing preprocessor error with macro

Tags: c++, debugging, macros, c-preprocessor

Is there a way that I can force a preprocessor macro in C++ to emit an error? What I would like to do is define a macro `UNKNOWN`. I'm writing some code for a robot, and I don't yet know where all of the electronics are being plugged in. I'd like to be able to define the ports in some header file, like

```
const int MOTOR_PORT = 1;
const int FAN_PORT = 2;
//etc.
```

However, when I reach a port that I don't yet know, I want to be able to write something like

```
const int LED_PORT = UNKNOWN;
```

In debug mode, `UNKNOWN` would just be defined to some arbitrary value, like 0. However, when compiling in release mode, I want it to throw an error when `UNKNOWN` is used, so that unassigned ports don't end up in the final release. I know I can use the `#error` directive to force an error, but can I do something similar in a macro?

I've seen a solution using `static_assert`, but I unfortunately can't use C++11 for this platform.

Comment: You could try `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`.

Comment: I'm not using boost, and I'm reluctant to add another dependency just for this.

Comment: If you just omit to define UNKNOWN or define it to nothing, the particular code here would fail to compile. Or even just #define UNKNOWN (1/0)

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to retain the ability of `#error` to emit a custom error message, rather than just an unrelated error.

Comment: @WilliamKunkel That can't be done if you need to #error on use only. You could possibly force a somewhat descriptive linking error if you did `#define FAN_PORT SORRY_THE_FAN_PORT_IS_NOT_AVAILABLE`

Comment: just let u know, static_assert is now in stl for C++11

Comment: @texasbruce I'm well aware that it's in C++11, but the most recent compiler this platform supports is GCC 3.4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `#error` can't result from a macro expansion, you can ensure that the macro expands to something that must be diagnosed, like a syntax error.

For example:

```
#ifdef RELEASE
#define UNKNOWN @Invalid_use_of_UNKNOWN
#else
#define UNKNOWN 0
#endif

const int MOTOR_PORT = 1;
const int FAN_PORT = 2;
const int LED_PORT = UNKNOWN;

int main(void) {
    int x = LED_PORT;
}
```

The `@` character isn't part of C's basic character set, so its appearance outside a comment, character constant, or string literal should always result in an error message. (`$` would work, except that accepting `$` in identifiers is a common extension. `` ` `` would probably also work, but `@` stands out better.)

I've defined the macro so it produces a reasonable error message with gcc:

```
c.c:9:1: error: stray ‘@’ in program
c.c:9:22: error: ‘Invalid_use_of_UNKNOWN’ undeclared here (not in a function)
```

and with clang:

```
c.c:9:22: error: expected expression
const int LED_PORT = UNKNOWN;
                     ^
c.c:2:17: note: expanded from:
#define UNKNOWN @Invalid_use_of_UNKNOWN
                ^
1 error generated.
```

(There's a `_Pragma` operator corresponding to the `#pragma` directive. It would be nice if there were an `_Error` operator as well, but there isn't.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, this does not produce a complier error message like #error, but would compile in debug and fail in release:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#   define UNKNOWN 1
#else
#   define UNKNOWN
#endif
const int port1 = UNKNOWN; // fail in release
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a division by zero which will throw a compiler error:
`#define UNKNOWN 0/0`

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to retain the ability of `#error` to emit a custom error message.

Comment: Im afraid that this not possible, unfortunately `static_assert` is the thing you require for this and we also cant expand a preprocessor directive to another directive.

Comment: This isn't portable. Division by zero causes undefined behavior, so there's no guarantee that it will stop compilation.

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof` operator cannot be applied to an incomplete type, so try this:

```
// Declared, but not defined anywhere.
struct illegal_use_of_unknown_macro;
#define UNKNOWN (sizeof (illegal_use_of_unknown_macro))
```